# React JS props not working .. Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to print output in react js using arrays and props. The result should be displayed as 2 headings (h) and 2 paragraphs (p)
But it gives this error Error: Home(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

**Note file**

```
const Note = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Eggs",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]
export default Note;
```

**Home file**

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from "./Note";
import menu from "./menu";

function nCard(val)
{
    return(
        <menu
                h={val.h}
                p={val.p}
        />
    );
}
const Home = (props) =>
{     
    {Note.map(nCard)}
}
export default Home;
```

**menu file**

```
const menu = (props) =>
{    
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>{props.h}</h1>
        <p>{props.p}</p>
    </div>
    )
}
export default menu;
```

**Index js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import index from './index.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import servicescontent from "./servicescontent";
import Services from "./Services";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Home from "./Home";

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
        <Home/>
</BrowserRouter>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You need a return statement in your `Home` function. `return (<>{Note.map(nCard)}</>);`

Comment: @nullromo, the react fragment should not be necessary as an array is a valid return value for a react component; `return Note.map(nCard)` (without curly brackets, in this case) should work as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! its fixed the issue was <menu and return in Home

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a return statement

```
const Home = (props) => Note.map(nCard)
```

much simpler and cleaner

Comment: o yes i got it that was simple

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Home` function to include a `return`.

```js
const Home = (props) =>
{     
    return Note.map(nCard);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! its fixed the issue was <menu and return in Home

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement in your Home component. Also, first letter of your component name should be uppercase. So, updated code will be:

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from "./Note";
import Menu from "./menu";

function nCard(val)
{
    return(
        <Menu
                h={val.h}
                p={val.p}
        />
    );
}
const Home = (props) =>
{    

   return Note.map(nCard)
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! its fixed the issue was <menu and return in Home

Comment: ive another problem that i was trying to make it work for a lot of days. Can you help me with it? @mohit    Thank You,..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060803/i-want-to-add-2-const-arrays-in-1-file-of-react-js-for-example-is-below

Comment: I will try my best @MaryamNaveed