# I want to add 2 const arrays in 1 file of React JS. For example is below

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I Want to add 2 array const in 1 file in React JS.**

I want to print Breakfast Menu when a link is selected and Lunch Menu similarly but I want to keep them in 1 file

I didn't change the name of **Note** file because it gave an error of `file not found`

This is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/mareyam/Maryam-s-Company-Menu

**And here is my project structure:**

[image]

**Note file**

```
const BreakfastMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Eggs",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]

const LunchMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Tomato",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]


export default {BreakfastMenu, LunchMenu};
```

**breakfast file**

```
import React from 'react';
import BreakfastMenu from "./BreakfastMenu";
import Menu from "./Menu";

function nCard(val)
{
    return(
        <Menu
                h={val.h}
                p={val.p}
        />
    );
}
const Breakfast = (props) =>
{     
    return ( 
        BreakfastMenu.map(nCard)
    )
}
export default Breakfast;
```

Comment: `import BreakfastMenu from "./BreakfastMenu"` There is no file called `BreakfastMenu`

Comment: yes because if i rename file as **BreakfastMenu** it gives error for LunchMenu

Comment: Ok but you simply cannot import from a file that does not exist.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-euler-yxrb8?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Use exports as follows

```
// Note.js
const BreakfastMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Eggs",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]

const LunchMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Tomato",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]


export {BreakfastMenu, LunchMenu};
```

Then do the imports as follows.

```
import { BreakfastMenu } from "./Note";
import { LunchMenu } from "./Note";
```

Comment: ./src/Breakfast.js
Attempted import error: 'BreakfastMenu' is not exported from './BreakfastMenu'.

Comment: You need to import it from `Note.js` file. So do it as `import { BreakfastMenu } from "./Note";. Similarly, do it for `LunchMenu` as well.
`

Answer (score 0):

### **You will need to setup webpack in order to use `import` `export`**

**And then change your export/import like so:**

**`Note file`**

```
export { BreakfastMenu, LunchMenu };
```

**And to import:**

```
import { BreakfastMenu, LunchMenu } from "./Note";
```

Working example:

[image: Edit heuristic-raman-of93f]

Comment: its "./Note" not "./Menu" and it didnt work... :(

Comment: What is your file structure look like? Is your Note.js inside some folder?

Comment: Its inside src folder where all the other files mentioned ^ are located

Comment: Where do you put your `Note`? They are all the same level?

Comment: yes they all are in -> C:\Users\marya\helloworld2\src

Comment: May I have access to your codesanbox or your repository?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236775/discussion-between-maryam-naveed-and-ryan-le).

Comment: https://github.com/mareyam/Maryam-s-Company-Menu  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
export const BreakfastMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Eggs",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]

export const LunchMenu = [
  {
    id:1,
    h:"Tomato",
    p:"eggs",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    h:"Milk",
    p:"milk",
  }
]
```

SInce they are multiple arrays there can be one default but better still still export each of the array or function from the start.
Then In your import you can use curly brackets to access the functions or array block

```
import { BreakfastMenu, LunchMenu } from "./Note";
```

This works with multiple functions in the same JS file too.

Comment: cant use 2 exports

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me but this did.

Export your arrays from Note.js as others have shown:

```
// Note.js
export const BreakfastMenu = [ ...
export const LunchMenu = [ ...
```

Import the arrays into Breakfast.js like this:

```
// Breakfast.js
import * as Data from "./Note"
```

Reference the breakfast menu like this (based on the original question):

```
const Breakfast = (props) =>
{     
    return ( 
        Data.BreakfastMenu.map(nCard)
    )
}
```

The "import * as Foo" syntax allows you to import multiple objects (components, functions, whatever) from a single source file and reference them with the "Foo" prefix.